# iframe resize Viewport-relative units

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iframe with an external source

```
<iframe id="idIframe" src="https://ssl.myexternallink.php" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I would like to have the auto height based on the iframe content. I tried:

```
iframe {
display: block;
background: #dedede;
border: none;     
height: 100vh;        
width: 100vw;
overflow-x:hidden;
```

}

work perfectly, but if I change iframe remote page (via Ajax post), the iframe height does not refresh. I can not use solution whit timer like:

```
iframeElement.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
```

because being an external page I have a cross-origin access problem. Is there a solution? Thank you

Comment: There are no pure CSS/HTML solutions. JavaScript solutions do exist to get around the cross-origin issue, mostly relying on having the remote page do a `postMessage()` to your host page. Your best bet, if you don't want to write something from scratch, would be to Google for something like iframe height plugins.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing it purely in HTML/CSS.
Have a look at: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

It resolves all the issues that arise from cross domain limitations etc.